# Execute parallel tasks with async/await

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, async-await

I need to execute multiple async tasks in Silverlight.

Documentation of the 3rd party package states I can use

```
await Task.WhenAll()
```

Unfortunately silverlight only have `Task.WaitAll()` and it is not awaitable. If I try to use it I get deadlock (I assume - because whole thing freezes)

What is the proper pattern to use in async method?

Comment: That should be the other way around.  It's `WaitAll` that should be excluded from the silverlight API and WhenAll should be included.  Do you have the proper version of .NET installed?

Comment: FWIW, on my stock SL5 I only see `Task.WaitAll`; there is no `Task.WhenAll` I assume unless I install some 3rd party library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For Silverlight I assume you're using the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) package.

Since this (add-on) package cannot modify the (built-in) `Task` type, you'll find some useful methods in the `TaskEx` type. Including `WhenAll`:

```
await TaskEx.WhenAll(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could try to use [TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321473%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to have similar behaviour if I understand your question correctly. [Example](http://www.codethinked.com/net-40-and-systemthreadingtasks):

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    return "dummy value 1";
});

var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    return "dummy value 2";
});

var task3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    return "dummy value 3";
});

Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new[] { task1, task2, task3 }, tasks =>
{
    foreach (Task<string> task in tasks)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
    }
});
```