# Executing Tasks in Parallel - Silverlight

Tags: c#, asynchronous, silverlight, async-await

I want to start a bunch of tasks and wait for all of them to finish.

This question is more or less identical to this question:
[Executing tasks in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34375696/executing-tasks-in-parallel)

But, the answer is not same for Silverlight because there is no equivalent method to Task.WhenAll().

This should work, but I get an error

> Start may not be called on a promise-style task.

```
        foreach (var displayThumbnailTask in displayThumbnailTasks)
        {
            displayThumbnailTask.Start();
        }

        foreach (var task in displayThumbnailTasks)
        {
            await task;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Start may not be called on a promise-style task." is a somewhat misleading message for the simple thing: the task has already been started.

Thus, you may just omit the first loop.

Silverlight does not have `Task.WhenAll`, but if you are using `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`, it contains `TaskEx.WhenAll` which is the same.

```
await TaskEx.WhenAll(displayThumbnailTasks);
```

[Execute parallel tasks with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376084/execute-parallel-tasks-with-async-await)

Comment: Excellent. Exactly what I was looking for.